# i want to get ng-init value with ng-model in controller

Tags: angularjs

**i want the ng-init value in hiddenVal like stus**

```
$scope.delTodo = function(id) {

  $http.post('delete.php', {
    stus: $scope.delstatus,
    hiddenVal: $scope.hidn
  }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //$scope.todocontent = response.data;
  });
};
```

** HTML code **

```
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todocontent track by $index">
                <p class="cls-{{todo.inc_id}}">{{todo.todoName}}</p>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.delstatus" ng-click="delTodo(todo)" ng-true-value="'{{todo.inc_id}}'" ng-false-value="'{{todo.inc_id}}'"  />
                <input ng-model="hidn" ng-init="hidn='{{inc_id}}'" type="hidden" name="fname"  >{{hidn}}
        </li>
```

Comment: What's the problem  ?

Comment: the  ng-init value is not passed in hiddenValue variable

Comment: Don't use ng-init. It's explicitly documented as bad practice. Use `$scope.hidn = '1';` in the controller.

Comment: when i check into the console only the stus value is passed to delete.php page

Comment: thanks  jb nizet if i repalce 1 to {{ inc_id }} (inc_id comes from ng-repeat loop )

Comment: ng-repeat defines its own scope. So each `li` has its own scope, where hidn is written. Your code doesn't make much sense: each text input is bound to a variable that only exists in the ng-repeat scope, ans is thus inavailable in the controller scope. And all checkboxes are bound to the same parent scope flag.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help *("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.